# Trouble mounting network drive

Tags: networking, ubuntu, mount, drive

I'm using the following command to mount a network drive:

```
sudo mount -t cifs //192.168.15.10/web -o username=user,password=pass /mnt/fileserver
```

I've verified that the location, username, and password are all correct with the network administrator.  But I'm not able to access it via `/mnt/fileserver`

I should point out that the destination folder is on a windows file server.

Answer (score 0):

Is the Windows file server part of a domain?  If so, you may need to use domain\user for the username.

Comment: I can mount another shared folder on this computer with a different user and using `/shared` instead of `/web`

Comment: Permissions on /shared may be open to the Everyone group instead of a Domain Users or some other group which requires a domain username. I would guess /web is locked down further than /shared is.